# AdWhirl causing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, adwhirl

I am using the latest version of AdWhirl to serve Ads from AdMob(+AdSense),InMobi,mdotm and Millennial Media.  I am getting a lot of;

Exception class java.lang.NullPointerException

Source method AdWhirlLayout.handleAd()

Stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:217)
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$3(AdWhirlLayout.java:205)
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:390)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is causing a large amount of force closing and upsetting my users, does anyone have any ideas what is causing this and how to fix.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AdWhirl has had a new release since this exception.  Is anybody still seeing these errors?  This may have been some weird case where there was a bad configuration that causes a Ration object to be populated with null values, which caused the NPE when a string was formatted with one of these fields.  All the fields in the ration have a value by default.